# What is the best way to forecast birthrates for the next 10 years?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models

I am new to forecast modeling and was curious what sort of model/modeling procedure would make the most sense for forecasting birth rates into 10 years into the future.

It seems to me like birth rates are stochastic rather than deterministic, am I right? Are linear regressions and ARIMA models unsuitable for forecasting birth rates because of the stochasticity?

Here is a simple line graph showing how birth rates (per woman) have changed over the past few decades:
[image]

Comment: You may be interested in the UN's WPP forecasts and associated methodological publications: https://population.un.org/wpp/

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.

Comment: I have had to do this--back c. 2005 I needed to make demographic projections for 2015 - 2025 in the US.  The process can become involved and complex, because an accurate projection will account for *current* populations and important characteristics including their ages and locations.  It will then "age" these populations according to mortality tables and allow them to migrate according to Census data (or projections).  Thus, what "makes sense" for you will depend on why you're doing this, your accuracy needs, and how much time and effort you have available to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to Chris' comment, I'll attempt to answer the actual question by clarifying a bit the nomenclature.

Most variable pairs ($X$, $Y$) (such as time and fertility rate in your example) we can perform statistical analysis have a relation which are neither "deterministic" or "stochastic".

- Deterministic relations are when information regarding one of the variables gives all the information on the value of the other. Example : $X$ is number of gallons bought by a customer at a gas station and $Y$ is total price paid by that customer. Obviously, $Y$ can be completely inferred from $X$ if we know the gas price per gallon.
- "Stochastic relations" isn't really standard nomenclature AFAIK, but the closest definition to the way you present it is when information regarding one of the variables gives no information on the value of the other. Example $X$ is the zodiacal sign of the customer ($Y$ unchanged from previous example).

Obviously, deterministic relations are of no interest for statistical analysis, and they are of no help in stochastic relations. Statistical analysis is useful for "middle cases", where information on one variable gives *some* information on the other's value. In the gas station example, it could be for example $X$ is the brand of the customer's car, or his annual income, age, etc. We say that the variables are (at least partially) *correlated*.

To answer your question on how you should predict the future fertility rates, I see two ways of going about it :

- try to predict the rate from features. Question to explore : What other factors could I look at which could be more related to fertility rate, and thus help me predict it more accurately (country GDP, etc ?) ? Can I have access to high-confidence prediction for these features for the following years ?
- try to predict from just the time, by fitting a curve to your data, but I feel like this would fail as many underlying causes varying very non-linearly with time happened over the last 40 years..